# What structure should i use to create a graphical editor

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, editor

I want to create an graphics editor ( Actionscript3  ).

So far i made the main class as a Singleton that holds 3 classes : Display ( sprite ), Input ( The input manager ) and Tools ( Tool manager ). The more stuff i add to my project, the more it gets complicated and buggy

The question : is there any defined approach how to do this. Maybe some idea of what design patterns should i use to archive this or structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES there certainly is a way to structure an application in Actionscript 3.0 and it comes in the form of PureMVC.

It is a moderate learning curve but there is a good tutorial on the site for each type of language that PureMVC supports.

You essentially have a facade which is in charge of your application and then a model or multiple models which are represented by mediators which are your view.

If you are serious about creating a good application using best practices, then go and check it out and take time to learn how to use the framework.

[PureMVC](https://github.com/PureMVC/puremvc-as3-standard-framework/wiki)

Comment: PureMVC is pretty good, but I'll recommend [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) as well. It's also a MVC design pattern and quite intuitive to use.

Comment: Yes robot legs is good and has dependency injection, but the use of mediators to steward the view components in PureMVC nudges it fur me.